# How to add comments in a code available on GitHub?

Tags: python, github, comments

I am trying to understand a Python code available on GitHub. The project is kind of large, when I understand the code available in one file and try to understand the code in another file, I forget some of the previous concepts (that I have understood in the previous files).

Is there any way I could add comments or a little description of each line while understanding the code in GitHub project? I know I can download the code and add comments using some IDE or Notepad etc. But it would be difficult for me while training, as I have to clone the project for training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you fork the code, and add comments to the code itself, on your copy of the repository. You can edit the files inside GitHub, no need to download the code.

Comment: Will it make changes to the original project?

Comment: @Nephophile no, you can't change someone else's code unless they explicitly give you access to the repo.

Comment: That is why I suggest you to fork the original code. It will create a copy of the code on your profile, and you can edit it freely, without affecting the original repository.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, SudE Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but you cannot do that. You cannot just edit someone's code like that, you could first fork the project and then add your comments. That would be a good way to work on the code with your personal comments. Or you could just download the code to add comments.

Comment: "You’re making changes in a project you don’t have write access to. Submitting a change will write it to a new branch in your fork ABC/XYZ, so you can send a pull request." Does this mean that the original project won't be affected?

Comment: the original project (the project you want to make a change in) WILL be affected. It will form another branch, a separate one with your change in it